# How to increase the performance of this function

Tags: php, performance, phalcon

How to increase the performance of following function in `phalcon` framework. There are thousands of records in the table. I tried different ways, but I am stuck the point. How can I increase the efficiency and reduce the execution time. Following are two methods:

```
public function currentmonthAction()
    {
        $payload = $this->request->getJsonRawBody();

        $this->setDB();
        $ticketsmodel = new Tickets();
        $fromcitycondition = "";
        if( isset($payload->city->id) )
        {   
            $fromcitycondition = "and fromcity='{$payload->city->id}'";
        }

        try{
            $date = new \Datetime($payload->date);
            $year = $date->format('Y');
            $month = $date->format('m');
            $month = '08';
            $daysInMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
            /* result for all cities passenger */
            $result = array();

            // get all cities permutations

            $tmpcitiesdata = array();
            $rawresultset = Tickets::find (
                array(
                    'columns' => 'fromcity,tocity',
                    'conditions' => "departure between '{$year}-{$month}-01' and '{$year}-{$month}-$daysInMonth' and tickettype in (1) ". $fromcitycondition,
                    'group' => 'fromcity,tocity'
                ));
            foreach ($rawresultset as $rawresult) {
                $tmpcitiesdata[$rawresult->fromcity.'-'.$rawresult->tocity]['fromcity'] = $rawresult->fromcity;
                $tmpcitiesdata[$rawresult->fromcity.'-'.$rawresult->tocity]['tocity'] = $rawresult->tocity;
            }

            //var_dump($rawresultset);
            // get tickets sold based on cities combinations

            $total = 0;

            foreach ($tmpcitiesdata as $tmpcities) {
                $rawresultset = Tickets::find (
                array(
                    'columns' => 'customer',
                    'conditions' => "departure between '{$year}-{$month}-01' and '{$year}-{$month}-$daysInMonth' and tickettype in (1) and fromcity=". $tmpcities['fromcity']." and tocity=".$tmpcities['tocity'],
                    'group' => 'customer'
                ));

                $totalsoldRaw = count($rawresultset);

                // get ticket cancellations 
                $rawresultset = Tickets::find (
                array(
                    'conditions' => "departure between '{$year}-{$month}-01' and '{$year}-{$month}-$daysInMonth' and tickettype in (3) and fromcity=". $tmpcities['fromcity']." and tocity=".$tmpcities['tocity']
                ));

                //make sure cancellations are tickets cancellations not booking cancellations

                foreach($rawresultset as $rawresult)
                {
                    $resultNumber = Tickets::find("departure='$rawresult->departure' and seatno={$rawresult->seatno} and id < {$rawresult->id} and tickettype = 1" );
                    if( count($resultNumber) > 0 ){
                        $totalsoldRaw = $totalsoldRaw-1;
                    }
                }

                $total += $totalsoldRaw;

                array_push($result, array('total' => $totalsoldRaw, 'fromcity' => Cities::findFirstById($tmpcities['fromcity'])->name, 'tocity' => Cities::findFirstById($tmpcities['tocity'])->name));
            }

            //sort result based on counts
            arsort($result);

            //cut result to max 6 cities
            $result = array_slice($result, 0, 6);

            $this->response->setContentType('application/json')
                ->setJsonContent(
                    array( 'totaltickets' => $total, "allcities" => $result )
                );
            $this->response->send();
            return;
        }
        catch(\PDOException $e)
        {
            $this->response->setStatusCode('422','Invalid Payload');
            $this->response->setContentType('application/json')
                ->setJsonContent(array(
                    'flash' => array(
                        'class' => 'danger',
                        'message' => $e->getMessage()
                    )
                ));
            $this->response->send();
            return;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use count instead of count(result of find). Also are you sure in // get ticket cancellations you don't need group ? Then you can select all tickets for customers in 1,3 tickettype and then filter resultset.

Also can't your first `$rawresulset` can't be:

```
$rawresultset = Tickets::find (
                array(
                    'columns' => 'customer,fromcity,tocity,tickettype ',
                    'conditions' => "departure between '{$year}-{$month}-01' and '{$year}-{$month}-$daysInMonth' and tickettype in (1,3)".$fromcitycondition
                    'group' => 'customer,fromcity,tocity'
                ));
```

?

```
$ticketCanccelations = $rawresultset->filter(function($row){
    if($row->tickettype == 3) {
        return $row;
    }

});

$resultNumber = Tickets::count("departure='$rawresult->departure' and seatno={$rawresult->seatno} and id < {$rawresult->id} and tickettype = 1" );
```

Comment: Hi Juri, thanks a lot for helping. can you share with me your email , skype , fb or any other contact detail . i am new with phalcon and want to discus directly with you if i need. can you guide me  best practices?

Comment: my skype name is faysalpk18 and faysalpk34@gmail.com

Comment: Nope, i won't waste time for this. If you want help outside of stack i would recommend phalcon slack or forum. If you want my direct help then you have to pay for this.